# React Native, how to execute a component's method from App.js when using stack navigation

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-navigation-stack, react-native-fcm

I finished a React Native course, and I'm trying to make a chat app to practice.

**Summarize the problem:**

- I have 2 screens ,**ContactList.js** and **ChatRoom.js**
- I have a Navigation stack with these two screens **Navigation.js**
- The Navigation component is imported and rendered in **App.js**
- I added FCM module to handle notifications

The goal is to execute the function that loads messages in the chatroom **_loadMessages()**, when the app receives a notification on foreground state. And to execute the function (I didn't create it yet) to update unread message in a global state.

**What I've tried**

I followed react native firebase docs,  I have a function that handle notification on foreground declared inside **App.js**. The problem is that I can't tell the other components (the screens) to execute their functions. The "Ref" method can't be used cause I'm not calling the child component (the screens) directly inside the **App.js**, I'm calling and rendering the **Navigation.js** Stack instead.

So, in this case, when we have a navigation component called on app.js, how can we tell other components to execute a function that is declared inside them?

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

export default function App() {

  requestUserPermission = async () => {
    //On récupere le token
    const token = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log('TOKEN: ' + token)
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  }

  handleForegroundNotification = () => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    this.requestUserPermission();
    this.handleForegroundNotification();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Navigation />
  )
}
```

**Navigation.js**

```js
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation"
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack"
import ContactList from '../Components/ContactList'
import ChatRoom from '../Components/ChatRoom'

const ChatStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ContactList: {
        screen: ContactList,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Contacts'
        }
    },
    ChatRoom: {
        screen: ChatRoom,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Conversation'
        }

    }
})

export default createAppContainer(ChatStackNavigator)
```

**ChatRoom.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Alert, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { sendMessage } from '../API/sendMessageApi'
import { getMessages } from '../API/getMessagesApi'
import MessageItem from './MessageItem'

class ChatRoom extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.message = ""
        this.contact = this.props.navigation.getParam('contact')

        this.state = {
            defautInputValue: "",
            listMessages: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
    }

    _textInputChanged(text) {
        this.message = text
    }
    _sendMessage() {
        this.setState({ defautInputValue: " " });
        sendMessage('1', this.contact.id_contact, this.message).then(() => {
            this._loadMessages();
        });
    }

    _loadMessages() {
        getMessages('1', this.contact.id_contact).then((data) => {
            this.setState({ listMessages: data, isLoading: false, defautInputValue: "" })
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadMessages();
    }
    _displayLoading() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={[styles.loading_container]}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="orange" />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        //console.log('Contact ID: ' + JSON.parse(this.contact))
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.contact}>
                    <View style={styles.image_container}>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.image}
                            source={{ uri: 'https://moonchat.imedramdani.com/avatar/' + this.contact.avatar }}
                        ></Image>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.username_container}>
                        <Text style={styles.username}>{this.contact.username}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {/* BODY */}
                <View style={styles.body}>
                    <FlatList
                        ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
                        onContentSizeChange={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
                        data={this.state.listMessages}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                            <MessageItem
                                message={item}
                            />}
                    >
                    </FlatList>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.input_container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this._textInputChanged(text)}
                        onSubmitEditing={() => this._sendMessage()}
                        defaultValue={this.state.defautInputValue}
                        placeholder="Aa"
                    ></TextInput>
                </View>
                {this._displayLoading()}
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#1d2733',
    },
    contact: {
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#1d2733',
        marginTop: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    username_container: {
        //backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex: 3,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-start'
    },
    username: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'white'
    },
    image_container: {
        //backgroundColor: 'blue',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    image: {
        //backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        height: 45,
        width: 45,
        marginLeft: 10,
        borderRadius: 25
    },
    body: {
        //backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex: 1
    },
    input_container: {
        height: 75,
        //backgroundColor:'blue',
        padding: 5
    },
    input: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 25,
        borderColor: '#D5D5D5',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    loading_container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
});

export default ChatRoom
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I set up a solution that worked, but I don't know if it is a proper way.

I restored **App.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Root from './Root'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './Store/configureStore'

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

I created a now component **Root.js** which contains notification handler

```js
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Root extends React.Component {

    requestUserPermission = async () => {
        //On récupere le token
        const token = await messaging().getToken();
        console.log('TOKEN: ' + token)
        const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
        const enabled =
            authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
            authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

        if (enabled) {
            console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
        }
    }

    handleForegroundNotification = () => {
        const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
            console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
            const action = { type: "RELOAD_MESSAGES", value: '1' }
            this.props.dispatch(action)
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.requestUserPermission();
        this.handleForegroundNotification();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigation />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loadyourself: state.loadyourself
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Root)
```

The store is provided in **App.js** to let **Root.js** access the global state.

When a notification is received at foreground, the **Root.js** update a key in the global state named "loadyourself". When the state is updated, the **ChatRoom.js** which is connected to the store too, trigger the **componentDidUpdate()**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.loadyourself == "1") {
        this._reloadMessages();
    }
}
```

of course, to avoid the infinite loop, the **_reloadMessages()** restore default value in the global state of loadyourself key

```
_reloadMessages() {
    const action = { type: "RELOAD_MESSAGES", value: '0' }
    this.props.dispatch(action)
    getMessages('1', this.contact.id_contact).then((data) => {
        this.setState({ listMessages: data })
    });
}
```

The messages are updated, the global state is re-initialized, the componentDidUpdate() does not trigger until next notification.

It works. Like I said, I don't know if there is a more proper way, I'm new in React-Native (2 weeks). I am open to other solutions